# SherlockActivity with GridView and onItemClick

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have adapted my app to use the SherlockActivity but since I have done so I cant get any clicks to trigger on my grid view. Below is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="@android:color/white">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid"
            style="@style/dashboard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="20.0dip" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

My onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid);

    final ImageAdapter imageAdpt = new ImageAdapter(this);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdpt);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Class<?> c = imageAdpt.getImageClass(position);
            if(c != null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, c);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Does it have to do anything with focus?

Comment: Are you inflating any other layout in the gridview in your imageAdpt class?

Comment: In getView: LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 0):

Hi After all I was inflating a menu leftover from before!

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
}
```

I replaced it to this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


   menu.add("Search")
       .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
   return true;
}
```